# Trouble understanding OCAML power function

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm trying to make sense of this Caml function to calculate the n-th power of a number.

```
let rec iterate n f d =
    if n = 0 then d
    else iterate (n-1) f (f d)

let power i n =
    let i_times a = a * i in
        iterate n i_times 1
```

I understand what it does conceptually, but I am having trouble understanding the `i_times` bit.

Per my understanding, `i_times` takes a value `a` and returns `a*i`, whre `i` is passed onto `power` upon calling it. In the expression where `i_times` is defined, it's followed by `1`, so wouldn't this mean that `i_times 1`, all together, is evaluated to `1*i`?

In this case, I fail to see how 3 parameters are being passed to `iterate`. Why doesn't it just end up being 2, that is `n` and `i_times 1`?

I know this is a pretty basic function, but I'm just getting started with functional programming and I want to make sense of it.

Comment: Why do you assume that `i_times` should be applied to `1`, but not that `n` should be applied to the result of `i_times 1`? And if it does work as you think, how would you pass `i_times` as an argument to `iterate` without applying it to the next argument?

Comment: Fair questions. Jeffrey's assumption was correct: I didn't assume what you said because `n` isn't a function. But your last question made me reflect on the implications of my original assumptions. It did click in, now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you're asking how OCaml parses a series of juxtaposed values.

This expression:

```
f a b c
```

is iterpreted as a call to a function `f` that passes 3 separate parameters. It is not parsed like this:

```
f a (b c)
```

which would be passing 2 parameters to f.

So indeed, three parameters are being passed to `iterate`. There are no subexpressions in the list of parameters, just three separate parameters.

Why didn't you figure that the subexpression `n i_times` would be evaluated before calling `iterate`? The reason (I suspect) is that you know that `n` isn't a function. But the parsing of the language doesn't depend on the types of things. If you wrote `(n i_times)` (with parentheses) it would be parsed as a call to `n` as a function. (This would, of course, be an error.)

Comment: Thank you, this 100% answers my question. So basically when I pass `i_times` to `iterate` I'm saying, "here's a function that takes a parameter and returns that parameter multiplied by the constant `i` (even though it's not a constant per se, it's one inside the scope of `i_times`)," I'm passing no computed value at that time.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how it works. Functions in OCaml are first-class values that can be passed to other functions and returned as the result of a function.